# How to kill a sleep process using a script

Tags: bash

I want to write a script that will do the following things:

1. start a sleep 500 command in the foreground.
2. then send the sleep 500 command in the background so that I can get my prompt back

I have tried doing this inside the script:

```
sleep 500
kill `pidof sleep`
```

But when I am running the script, the sleep command does not stop and I do not get my prompt back.

Comment: `Ctrl`+`z` then `bg` and then `kill %1`?

Comment: trying to emulate ctrl+z action in a script. The script will start a sleep 500 command and from the script itself , the sleep process will be killed/suspended

Comment: What you are seeking isn't possible. Re. emulating ctrl+Z: that signal sent via ctrl+Z happens externally. So either you'll have to have multiple processes/threads that suspends `sleep` or send the signal externally. Once `sleep` starts, the shell simply waits - there's no other way to do interrupt it. Background process seems like the ideal candidate here. Why do you not want to use it?

Comment: The [XY](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378) problem is asking about your attempted solution rather than your actual problem.

Comment: i was suspecting this. Thank you for confirming this. This came as a multipart assignment for my course. I was stuck with this part.

Comment: @Cyrus the actual question was: 1. start a sleep 500 command in the foreground. 2. send the sleep 500 command in the background to get the prompt back. I think I posted the same thing here.

Comment: There is actually a way you can do this, but it requires setting a separate `trap` for each signal you want to handle. I'm looking for the proper dup.

Comment: This isn't the exact one I recall, but this provides a good discussion [sleep, wait and Ctrl+C propagation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/478563/197080)

Comment: Tried to understand this. But it seems a little bit complicated for me. If you could provide the exact dup, that would be great. Anyways thank you showing this @DavidC.Rankin

Comment: What you wrote above as _the actual question was: …_ doesn't speak of _a script_; doing it interactively is easy.

Comment: For ***emulating***  `Ctrl+Z`, then  `bg`, you have to emulate a *`terminal`* in order to run an *interactive shell*!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't find the exact dup I was looking for so here is a short example. If I understand what you are wanting, you want to start a `sleep` process and then at any time you want to be able to quit the sleep process returning you to your prompt. You say "background" the sleep process, but I'm not sure whether you actually need to background it to let it expire on its own in the future, or if just need a way out of the sleep whenever you choose (that would make more sense)

While you can simply use <kbd>Ctrl + C</kbd> to interrupt the process, you won't be returned to your script. So if you need a way to return to your script, you need to `trap` `SIGINT`. When you set a `trap 'some command' SIGINT` your script will intercept and process the interrupt and control will return to the point following the `sleep` command, e.g.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

## set trap
trap 'printf "\n[Ctrl + C] SIGINT intercepted\n"' SIGINT

printf "sleeping 500...\n"

sleep 500

## rest of script after sleep
printf "control returned to script\ncontinuing to process commands\n"
```

**Example Running Script Above**

```
$ bash trap_int.sh
sleeping 500...
^C
[Ctrl + C] SIGINT intercepted
control returned to script
continuing to process commands
```

That may or may not satisfy what you need. However, you can build on that to control what happens after an interrupt a bit further. When you set the `trap` you can have it call a separate function within your script that can conditionally execute code and end the script on that separate branch by calling `exit`. That has the effect of transferring control back to your script to only execute commands from the path that starts with the function you specify. This provides away to avoid executing code that follows the sleep, while providing a separate execution path in your script to run whatever is needed after interrupt from sleep.

**Conditionally Executing Commands After Interrupt**

Rather than just `sleep 500`, in the next example we will repeatedly call two functions `sleep_a` which calls a nested sleep function `sleep_b`. Following `SIGINT` control will be passed to a function named `handle_interrupt` where additional commands can be executed calling `exit` to exit the script and return you to your prompt. An additional function called `actual_exit` is called to perform the exit.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

## function called to exit, returning you to prompt
function actual_exit
{
    printf "  Exiting after '%s'\n\n" "$1"
    exit
}

## function called after SIGINT, calls actual_exit to disply signal caught
function handle_interrupt
{
    printf "\n  Signal SIGINT Caught! [ctrl + c]\n\n"
    actual_exit 'SIGINT'
}

## set trap
trap handle_interrupt SIGINT      # calls handle_interrupt on [ctrl + c]

declare -i idx=0    ## loop counter

function sleep_b
{
    printf "\nentering sleep_b\n"
    sleep 2
    printf "executing post sleep_b index: %s\n" $((idx++))
}

function sleep_a
{
    printf "\nentering sleep_a\n"
    sleep 2
    printf "executing post sleep_a index: %s\n" $((idx++))
    sleep_b
}

## repeatedly call nested sleep until signal received
while :; do
    sleep_a
done

## rest of script after sleep
printf "control returned to script\ncontinuing to process commands\n"
```

When the script is interrupted, the command following below the `while` loop are never reached as the script exits through the code path provided by the function called on `SIGINT`.

**Providing Common Commands On `exit`**

You can add yet another layer of execution by setting a `trap` on `EXIT`. If you have a collection of signal you set a `trap` for, you can have all end though a common function. For example if you monitored multiple signals each returning to a function ultimately calling `exit`, you can set a `trap` on `EXIT` calling a final function holding commands to be executed before the script exits.

For example, you could do:

```
trap final_function EXIT  # calls final_function on exit() from script
```

where a call to `exit` anywhere within the script would invoke the `trap` on `EXIT` calling `final_function` before returning control back to you.

Let me know if something like one of the incremental levels of handling canceling sleep though an interrupt will do what you need. Technically it doesn't "background" `sleep`, but does allow you to cancel the sleep at any moment conditionally returning control within your script to wherever you choose.